# logical dataframe with numerical dataframe and substitute FALSE by NA with R

Tags: r, na

this is probably a very stupid question to be asked here, but I'm an absolute beginner in [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I looked everywhere and tried multiple things and I couldn't solve the problem.

So I have a two dataframes: df which contains numeric values and [na](/questions/tagged/na)'s and another, j which contains only TRUE, FALSE or [na](/questions/tagged/na)'s and I want to recover from df the values corresponding to the TRUE positions of j, the FALSE ones replace their values by NA and the NA to be maintained as NA.

Example:

```
df
           12h      13h      14h       15h       16h
00003      1        NA       10        NA        NA     
00017      NA       NA       15        18        NA
00018      33       12       25        NA        33
00021      20       12       11        NA        7
00025      NA       21       21        1         9
00031      3        11       NA        NA        3


j
           12h      13h      14h       15h       16h
00003      NA       NA       FALSE     NA        NA     
00017      NA       NA       FALSE     TRUE      NA
00018      FALSE    FALSE    TRUE      NA        NA
00021      TRUE     FALSE    FALSE     NA        TRUE
00025      NA       TRUE     NA        TRUE      FALSE
00031      TRUE     FALSE    NA        NA        TRUE
```

Being the result something like this:

```
 df.results
           12h      13h      14h       15h       16h
00003      NA       NA       NA        NA        NA     
00017      NA       NA       NA        18        NA
00018      NA       NA       25        NA        NA
00021      20       NA       NA        NA        7
00025      NA       21       NA        1         NA
00031      3        NA       NA        NA        3
```

Not sure if I made myself clear but I really would appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution

```
is.na(j) <- j == FALSE
df[] <- df[as.matrix(j)]
df
#       X12h X13h X14h X15h X16h
# 00003   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 00017   NA   NA   NA   18   NA
# 00018   NA   NA   25   NA   NA
# 00021   20   NA   NA   NA    7
# 00025   NA   21   NA    1   NA
# 00031    3   NA   NA   NA    3
```

---

**A quick explanation**

First, we are converting all the `FALSE` entries in `j` to `NA`s using the `is.na<-` assignment function and then we are converting it to a matrix in order to use it as row/column indexes within `df`. The `NA` indices will return `NA`s while the `TRUE` will provide the correct indices. Though the output will be a vector, thus we are using the `[<-` function in order to preserve the original structure of `df`